# Creating, saving and displaying items in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am trying to create a reporting service for my app, it allows the creation of PDF and CSV files (possible future support for more file types).

I can create the files just fine, but I'm trying to find a way to save my created file in a public folder that is retained even if the app is deleted, and also to let the user open it the moment it was created.

Just to clarify I want the download to invoke the platform specific download manager, so the notification service would indicate to the user a download has happened.

I understand DependencyService is going to be my answer but I'm a bit lost within the platform APIs, if anyone can help me navigate that territory...

I feel like many people asked this question but nonetheless I can't find a solution that works.

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question.  You've given a broad description of a problem but haven't really indicated what you've done to try and solve it.  I'd suggest you start by breaking the problem up and focus on solving each part. 1) for each platform, where can I write files so they are shared?  2) in Xamarin how do I do that?  3) How do I display that file to the user?  And so on...

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=xamairn+write+to+a+public+folder

Comment: You just can't save file everywhere in iOS if you don't use other app (opening sharing options with this file will help)